# Is there a reverse function of .in_ in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to organize my blog posts by "tags", which is just a string of words separated by commas. I want to be able to select a tag which would only show posts that have that tag somewhere in the string of tags.

For example:
Post1
- tags: "world politics, technology"

Post2
-tags: "technology"

Selecting "world politics" - I only want Post1. Selecting "technology" I want Post1 and Post2.

I'm trying to use the .in_ filter function, but as of right now it won't select anything

```
@app.route('/index/<tag>')
def taggedindex(tag):
    posts = Post.query.filter(Post.tags.in_(tag)).all()
```

If I use

```
posts = Post.query.filter(tag == tag).all()
```

It will only select direct matches, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current model is not in [1st normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), since `Post.tags` is not atomic, or in other words does not contain a single value of its domain. This makes querying against it more challenging. For example the solution offered by @blakebjorn suffers from false positives. Say you have posts 1 and 2 with tags `"nice, boat"` and `"ice, cool"`, and you're looking for posts with tag `"ice"`. The predicate `tags LIKE '%ice%'` will match `nice` as well, and so you get both posts 1 and 2 as a result:

```
In [4]: session.add_all([Post(tags="nice,boat"), Post(tags="ice,cool")])

In [5]: session.commit()

In [6]: session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.like("%ice%")).all()
Out[6]: [<__main__.Post at 0x7f83b27e5b70>, <__main__.Post at 0x7f83b27e5be0>]
```

The proper solution is to split the tags into single tags. In order to avoid repeating the other fields in `Post` you must then split tags to their own table:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True)
```

Because a post can have many tags and a tag can be related to many posts, you need an association table to connect the two, also called a "secondary" table in SQLAlchemy:

```
post_tag = db.Table(
    "post_tag",
    db.Column("post_id", db.ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True),
    db.Column("tag_id", db.ForeignKey("tag.id"), primary_key=True)
)
```

You would then probably want to map this relationship in your models as a [many to many relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many):

```
class Post(db.Model):
    ...
    tags = db.relationship("Tag", secondary="post_tag")
```

The relationship can be used to query for posts with certain tag(s):

```
In [15]: session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.any(name="ice")).all()
Out[15]: [<__main__.Post at 0x7fb45d48a518>]

In [24]: session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.any(Tag.name.in_(["boat", "ice"]))).all()
Out[24]: [<__main__.Post at 0x7fb45d3d0470>, <__main__.Post at 0x7fb45d48a518>]
```

Using an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) you can hide the fact that tags are not just strings, but models in their own right:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    ...
    tag_objects = db.relationship("Tag", secondary="post_tag")
    tags = db.association_proxy("tag_objects", "name",
                                creator=lambda name: Tag(name=name))
```

Association proxies also [support basic queries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#querying-with-association-proxies):

```
In [22]: session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags.any(Tag.name == "ice")).all()
Out[22]: [<__main__.Post at 0x7fb45d48a518>]
```

and (a bit non intuitively, since it proxies to a scalar attribute):

```
In [23]: session.query(Post).filter(Post.tags == "ice").all()
Out[23]: [<__main__.Post at 0x7fb45d48a518>]
```

Note that we made `Tag.name` unique, so inserting will fail if using an existing tag name. This can be solved for example using the ["unique object" pattern](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/UniqueObject).

Comment: Wow, thank you for your incredibly detailed response; you are absolutely right I began to snag false positives and realized the organization of my models was causing all sorts of issues. This is very helpful for a newbie in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

use the sql `like` operator with wildcards

```
@app.route('/index/<tag>')
def taggedindex(tag):
    posts = Post.query.filter(Post.tags.like(f'%{tag}%')).all()
    # case insensitive
    # posts = Post.query.filter(Post.tags.ilike(f'%{tag}%')).all()
```